# Firebase Rules for Realtime Database Without Using Firebase Authentication

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pretty new with Firebase Service, but I've already completed code for my iOS app which is responsible for Firebase Realtime Database Interaction.

Now I want to make my app secured and protect it with Firebase Rules. There is a problem that I'm using my own authentication for users and therefore I don't use Firebase Auth.

So the question is how can I secure my database using Firebase Rules and without Firebase Auth.

Comment: You can't use security rules based on the currently authenticated user without also using Firebase Authentication.

Comment: If you open the project for the [firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com) then you can go over to the Database section and set the firebase rules from there (you'll see a tab called "rules")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: To my knowledge, it's not possible to use your custom authentication system **directly** within Firebase.

**Assumption: You have an authentication server which Firebase Admin SDK (can be/has already been) integrated.**

You need to create custom tokens in order to use your authentication within the Database/Storage:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens

> Once authenticated, this identity will be used when accessing other
>   Firebase services, such as the Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud
>   Storage. Furthermore, the contents of the JWT will be available in the
>   auth object in your Firebase Realtime Database Security Rules and the
>   request.auth object in your Cloud Storage Security Rules.

*Omitting Java and Python from the upper link*

In server:

```
// Step 1: Your client has sent the credentials.
// Step 2: Fetch the client's unique id, and create a custom token with the Admin SDK.

var uid = "some-uid"; 

admin.auth().createCustomToken(uid)
  .then(function(customToken) {
    // Send token back to client
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
  });
```

Then in iOS part:

```
// Step 1: Login with your own authentication system.
// Step 2: Send your credentials to your server, and fetch the customToken.
// Step 3: Sign in with FIRAuth:

[[FIRAuth auth] signInWithCustomToken:customToken
                           completion:^(FIRUser *_Nullable user, NSError *_Nullable error) {
  // ...
}];
```

Answer (score 3):

As Stevenson said , you cant use security rules without firebase authentication.

To use firebase authentication, please follow steps below

You can get firebase token from server along with your own auth token , then you can use custom token authentication api
     (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth) to authenticate with firebase

1. To know about custom token generation on server side , follow this, https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens
2. One common pattern for storing user data in the Realtime Database is to store all of your users in a single users node whose children are the uid values for every user. If you wanted to restrict access to this data such that only the logged-in user can see their own data, your rules would look something like this:

Example:

```
{
      "rules": {
            "users": {
              "$uid": {
                ".read":  "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
                ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
              }
            }
          }
 }
```

Here **auth** is authorization object.**uid** is the unique token(user id for above case)  which you send from custom token generation on server side.For more details, please check firebase documentation on user security.